# Error al realizar consulta en firebird con fdb en python 3

Tags: python, sql, firebird

Trato de realizar una consulta en una base de datos usando Firebird, este es mi código:

```
import fdb
import os

ruta = 'localhost:C:/Users/Beto/Documents/Proyectos python/Ruby/sama.fdb'

try:
    con = fdb.connect(
    dsn = ruta,
    user = 'sysdba',
    password = '*******',
    charset = 'utf-8'
    )
    print('Conectado !!')
except:
    print('Fallo la conexion', ruta)



cx = con.cursor()
sql = 'SELECT * FROM user'
cx.execute(sql)

filas = cx.fetchall()
print(filas)
con.commit()
con.close()
```

Pero obtengo el mensaje de error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Beto\Documents\Proyectos python\Ruby\fire.py", line 22, in <module>
    cx.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Users\Beto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\fdb\fbcore.py", line 3573, in execute
    self._ps = PreparedStatement(operation, self, True)
  File "C:\Users\Beto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\fdb\fbcore.py", line 2182, in __init__
    "Error while preparing SQL statement:")
fdb.fbcore.DatabaseError: ('Error while preparing SQL statement:\n- SQLCODE: -104\n- Dynamic SQL Error\n- SQL error code = -104\n- Token unknown - line 1, column 15\n- user', -104, 335544569)
```

Answer (score 1):

la definición de tu dsn es incorrecta, no tiene que llevar la palabra `localhost:`, ya que estas definiendo una ruta en c:/ .

```
ruta = 'localhost:C:/Users/Beto/Documents/Proyectos python/Ruby/sama.fdb'
```

regularmente la extensión de la base de datos es .db

http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/python/fdb/getting-started.html

Comment: Como podría hacerle para no tener que escribir toda la ruta completa? es decir que el lenguaje mismo ubique donde esta mi base

Comment: Cual es el path de tu base de datos? regularmente tiene extensión .db, no .fdb

Comment: @python, échale un ojo al módulo `os.path`. Dentro del mismo tienes funcionalidad para trabajar con rutas. Si estás en Python 3 puedes usar también `pathlib`.

Comment: Mi base de datos esta en la misma carpeta del proyecto @kikocorreoso

Comment: @python podría ser algo así `ruta = os.path.join(os.path.curdir, 'base_de_datos.db')` o, viendo que usas Python 3.5, puedes usar ``pathlib`` de la siguiente forma:`ruta = pathlib.Path('.', 'base_de_datos.db')` y cuando quieras usar la ruta como string simplemente usa `ruta.path`

Answer (score 0):

Ya uso php.pdo para conectar y lo hago así:

```
    try {
        $co = new PDO("firebird:dbname=mibdfb;role=mirol", 'SYSDBA', 'masterkey'); 
        $co->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $co = null;
        $inf = "ERROR: ConectaBD: " . $e->getMessage();
    }           
    return ($co);

    **-el nombre de la base de datos "mibdfb" es un alias que esta descrito en el fichero: aliases.conf, de esta manera:
      mibdfb = C:/Users/Beto/Documents/Proyectos python/Ruby/sama.fdb
```

Comment: Gracias a todos ya lo pude resolver